# CompileError: AsyncCompile: Wasm decoding failed: expected magic word

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, webassembly

While running my wasm code in unit testing a function, I am getting this error:

```
CompileError: AsyncCompile: Wasm decoding failed: expected magic word 00 61 73 6d, found 3c 21 44 4f @+0
```

Though I have successfully added the compiled wasm file to the directory and the main part is code is running with browser but not with tests.

The tests are running with tape and browserified.

```js
const imports = {
      env:{
        // paceOp: require('pace').op,
        consoleLog:console.log,
        perform: function(x,y){
          let pixel = options.changePixel(
            pixels.get(x, y, 0),
            pixels.get(x, y, 1),
            pixels.get(x, y, 2),
            pixels.get(x, y, 3),
            x,
            y
          );

          pixels.set(x, y, 0, pixel[0]);
          pixels.set(x, y, 1, pixel[1]);
          pixels.set(x, y, 2, pixel[2]);
          pixels.set(x, y, 3, pixel[3]);
        }
      }
    };
    const inBrowser = (options.inBrowser)?1:0;
    const test = (process.env.TEST)?1:0;
    fetch('./test.wasm').then(response =>
      response.arrayBuffer()
    ).then(bytes =>
      WebAssembly.instantiate(bytes, imports)
    ).then(results => {
      results.instance.exports.manipulatePixel(pixels.shape[0],pixels.shape[1],inBrowser, test);
        extraOperation();
    }).catch(err=>{
      console.log(err)
    });
```

Can someone please help me with it!!
Thanks in advance..

Comment: @Pointy its an arrow function without the braces which means the result is automatically returned and applying a return will cause errors as per the ES6 syntax.

Comment: Oh of course you're right, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

**The argument passed to `fetch()` is wrong.**

Take a look at your fetch response value. I think you'll find that whatever web server you are using is returning a document (perhaps a 404) when you request `fetch('./test.wasm')`.

I wouldn't be able to say where your `wasm` file is relative to this script, but judging by your use of `'./'`, maybe your intended use is: `fetch('test.wasm')`?

You can also see what I mean by rewriting these lines:

```js
fetch('./test.wasm').then(response) {
    console.log("Note the response text value: " + response);
    var ab = response.arrayBuffer();
    return ab;
})
```

If you pass the right path to `fetch`, the rest of this code may run just fine.